# How to close a port on the network

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, port

I ran an nmap scan on my (Ubuntu) computer on the local network and each time I found that port 80 is open. It's used by Apache.
I changed the security options so Apache will no longer respond to any access request from the LAN, but is there any way to close it so it doesn't appear in case of scan without killing the Apache service?

P.S.: I tried `ufw deny 80`
but it didn't work for me.

Comment: here the lan is just the example, it can be the wifi too, sometimes I used wifi in cafes, restaurant, public wifis ..... while working with on laptop. the port was opened by default when I installed apache for local dev and I've no intention to use it as a webserver.

Comment: what do you mean by the "Host", I scanned my pc which is an ubuntu machine looking for the opened port!

Comment: There we go. Ubuntu is what I was looking for. It's vital info for an adequate answer guy. :) Appache runs on pretty much everything

Comment: Sorry for that, when I posted the question I forgot that SuperUser could be windows Admins, which led to this confusion.

Comment: Did you try in appache to put the service on 127.0.0.1:80 ? It should make it still available to the host OS but not serve port 80 on the lan or WLAN adapter.

Comment: how to do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your site-enabled list.

`<Location "/">.

order Deny,allow.

Deny from all.

allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128.

</Location>`

This should limit Apache from serving to the localhost only.

Or

Change ports.conf so that it contains:
Listen 127.0.0.1:80 **only**.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Securing%20Apache

Comment: Thank you! you are so helpful! the last one work for me! and now I can use apache on my machine as a dev server and  prevent it from listening for incoming connection attempts.

Comment: cool, glad I could help!